# Search pattern to a special character with awk

Tags: awk, grep, pattern-matching

I have a file like the one below

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: WinREST HTTP Server/1.0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 89
WWW-Authenticate: ServiceAuth realm="WinREST", nonce="1828HvF7EfPnRtzSs/h10Q=="

<html><head><title>Unauthorized</title></head><body>Error 401: 
Unauthorized</body></html>
```

I need to get the nonce, that is just the 1828HvF7EfPnRtzSs/h10Q== in front og the word nonce=

I was using

```
grep -oP 'nonce="\K[^"]+' response.xml
```

but the P parameter no longer works.
how can I do the same with awk or even Grep with another parameter, maybe ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `sed`

```
$ sed -nE 's/.*nonce="([^"]+)"/\1/p' file

1828HvF7EfPnRtzSs/h10Q==
```

with `grep` pipeline

```
$ grep -oE 'nonce=\S+' file | cut -d= -f2- | tr -d '"'

1828HvF7EfPnRtzSs/h10Q==
```

Answer (score 1):

***Solution 1st:*** Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -F"\"" '/nonce/{print $(NF-1)}' Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** A `sed` solution too for same.

```
sed -n '/nonce=/s/\(.*nonce\)="\([^"]*\)\(.*\)/\2/p'  Input_file
```

Output will be `1828HvF7EfPnRtzSs/h10Q==` in both codes above.

Comment: I forgot to say that the nonce is in the same line with the previus line.
I corrected the example, and the file may contain more or less lines

Comment: @PedroCaldeira, I have modified both the solutions now please check and let me know then.

Comment: and if the pattern has "", like the following example, how do i get the number next to idOperation?

{"reqStatus":{"code":0,"message":"Success","success":true},"idOperation":"185-16-6"}

Comment: @PedroCaldeira, sorry didn't get it, please do let me know example will let you know on same then.

Comment: the pattern is idOperation,but I only want to get the number next  185-16-6, how do I do it.
I am trying to understand how awk and sed work

Comment: @PedroCaldeira, sorry where is `185-16-6` present in your data? Please explain it more clearly or if it is a new requirement then kindly do open a new thread.

Comment: its another example, but i will open a new thread then. Thanks